# Falsy: Why should I use !!! instead of ! (3 instead of 1 bang)

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between `!!!` and `!`?

Found at jasmine source code in the [`toBeFalsy`](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine/blob/master/src/core/matchers/toBeFalsy.js) matcher.

Results from chrome devtools

```
!!!undefined
true
!undefined
true
!!!null
true
!null
true
!!!0
true
!0
true
```

Comment: I'm not going to say that there is not no difference.

Comment: Maybe it was `!!` initially (convert anything to boolean), then the condition had to be inverted and the maintainer added another `!` operator without thinking. That, or they play [BlazBlue](http://blazblue.wikia.com/wiki/Bang_Shishigami) *way* too much.

Comment: There is no difference between ! and !!!

Answer (score 12):

> Is there any difference between !!! and !?

No. They are the same.

> Why should I use !!! instead of ! (3 instead of 1 bang)

To annoy programmers