# VueJS conditionally add an attribute for an element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In VueJS we can add or remove a DOM element using v-if:

```
<button v-if="isRequired">Important Button</button>
```

but is there a way to add / remove attributes of a dom element eg for the following conditionally set the required attribute:

```
Username: <input type="text" name="username" required>
```

by something similar to:

```
Username: <input type="text" name="username" v-if="name.required" required>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: While being not so obvious (hence the confusion) the documentation actually do says that if attribute value evaluates to false then attribute being omitted (https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)

Comment: Actually, the documentation says the attribute won't be added if *“…has the value of `null`, `undefined`, or `false`”*, which is different from a JS script evaluating to false. This means an empty string is falsy in JavaScript, but would still add the attribute to DOM. To prevent that you could try `v-bind:name="name || false"`

Comment: @AlexanderB If that's true, how can I pass explicit `false` to child component via a prop?

Comment: @BruceSun , If the attribute in context "unintentionally" disappears when you give it false value - try to pass it as a string `'false'`. In other cases when you need to control presence of non-boolean html attribute on the element you can use conditional rendering with `v-if` as suggested here:
 https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/7552#issuecomment-361395234

Comment: @AlexanderB I think I have to correct myself - I should say `attribute` but NOT `prop`. We can safely pass explicit `false` via a component property but NOT attribute (which is not recognised as a property). Am I correct?

Answer (score 227):

Try:

```
<input :required="test ? true : false">
```

**Update: It has changed in Vue 3, see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64598898**

Comment: Long form is `<input v-bind:required="test ? true : false">`

Comment: `anythingAtAll : ? true : false` (or `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; }`) in any language is ... _unseemly_. Just use `return (condition)` or, in this case, `<input :required="test">`

Comment: if you are sure that variable `test` is `boolean`, you can just use `:required="test"`

Comment: Please note that this depends on the component! It's possible that if your property accepts `String` value that by setting it to `false` you will get `type check` error. So set it to `undefined` instead of false. [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)

Comment: using `:required="required"` where `required` is a Boolean component property results in <el required="required"> for me

Comment: maybe that's valid? I've always added the attribute the standard way `<el required>`

Comment: Having a resulting `required="required"` in your markup is completely normal and standard. You can test this by creating a sample HTML file with a simple `required` attribute. Your browser will fill up the blanks by itself.

Comment: Note that this has changed with Vue 3, see one of the answers further down

Comment: what if we have to check string like ex: test == 'somestring' then its true else false , then how we do that ?

Comment: @AjayNamdev simply ```<input :required="test === 'somestring'">```

Answer (score 106):

Conditional rendering of attributes changed in Vue 3. To omit an attribute use `null` or `undefined`.

Vue 2:

```
<div :attr="false">
Result: <div>

<div :attr="null">
Result: <div>
```

Vue 3:

```
<div :attr="false">
Result: <div attr="false">

<div :attr="null">
Result: <div>
```

Comment: undefined works well with few of the Vue packages I am using

Comment: What if you need the attribute to be <div attr> instead of <div attr="something"> ?

Comment: Vue 3. Worked for me: ```:checked="item.checked ? true : null"`

Comment: Should this work for event handlers (e.g. `@click="val ? onClick : null"`

Answer (score 87):

Simplest form:

```
<input :required="test">   // if true
<input :required="!test">  // if false
<input :required="!!test"> // test ? true : false
```

Comment: Please note that this depends on the component! It's possible that if your property accepts `String` value that by setting it to `false` you will get `type check` error. So set it to `undefined` instead of false. [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)

Comment: @Syed  your answer using double exclamation points `!!`  I've never seen that syntax before yesterday and during a code review I came across this: -- `<input :required="!!!recipe.checked" v-model="recipe.pieType"><select :required="!!!recipe.checked" v-model="recipe.ingredients" :options="ingredients"></select>` 
Would you know what `!!!` (3) mean for a `:required` value? Thanks.

Comment: @Chris22 There is no difference between !test and !!!test, since !!!test is just !!(!test) and because !test is a boolean, !!(!test) is just its double negation, therefore the same. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25318045/1292050

Comment: @Syed thanks.  Following your link, [I found this one as well and I agree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30895846/falsy-why-should-i-use-instead-of-3-instead-of-1-bang/30895960#30895960). :^)

Comment: What @Syed said isn't untrue

Answer (score 24):

You can pass `boolean` by coercing it, put `!!` before the variable.

```
let isRequired = '' || null || undefined
<input :required="!!isRequired"> // it will coerce value to respective boolean
```

But I would like to pull your attention for the following case where the receiving component has defined `type` for props. In that case, if `isRequired` has defined type to be `string` then passing `boolean` make it type check fails and you will get Vue warning. To fix that you may want to avoid passing that prop, so just put `undefined` fallback and the prop will not sent to `component`

```
let isValue = false
<any-component
  :my-prop="isValue ? 'Hey I am when the value exist' : undefined"
/>
```

**Explanation**

I have been through the same problem, and tried above solutions !!
Yes, I don't see the `prop` but that actually does not fulfils what required here.

My problem -

```
let isValid = false
<any-component
  :my-prop="isValue ? 'Hey I am when the value exist': false"
/>
```

In the above case, what I expected is not having `my-prop` get passed to the child component - `<any-conponent/>` I don't see the `prop` in `DOM` but In my `<any-component/>` component, an error pops out of prop type check failure. As in the child component, I am expecting `my-prop` to be a `String` but it is `boolean`.

```
myProp : {
 type: String,
 required: false,
 default: ''
}
```

Which means that child component did receive the prop even if it is `false`. Tweak here is to let the child component to take the `default-value` and also skip the check. Passed `undefined` works though!

```
<any-component
  :my-prop="isValue ? 'Hey I am when the value exist' : undefined"
/>
```

This works and my child prop is having the default value.

Comment: This is what worked for me when working with select options (and the selected attribute)

Answer (score 23):

`<input :required="condition">`

You don't need `<input :required="test ? true : false">` because if **test** is *truthy* you'll already get the `required` attribute, and if **test** is *falsy* you won't get the attribute. The `true : false` part is redundant, much like this...

```
if (condition) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
// or this...
return condition ? true : false;
// can *always* be replaced by...
return (condition); // parentheses generally not needed
```

The simplest way of doing this binding, then, is `<input :required="condition">`

Only if the *test* (or *condition*) can be misinterpreted would you need to do something else; in that case Syed's use of `!!` does the trick.
   `<input :required="!!condition">`

Answer (score 10):

You can add colon before attribute (also can use conditions) like

```
<div :class="current? 'active': '' " > 
<button :disabled="InvalidForm? true : false " >
```

If you want to set a dynamic value like props then you also can use colon before attribute name like :

```
<Child :data="userList" />
```

Answer (score 9):

It's notable to understand that if you'd like to conditionally add attributes you can also add a dynamic declaration:

```
<input v-bind="attrs" />
```

where attrs is declared as an object:

```
data() {
    return {
        attrs: {
            required: true,
            type: "text"
        }
    }
}
```

Which will result in:

```
<input required type="text"/>
```

Ideal in cases with multiple attributes.

Answer (score 4):

You could write something like this:

```
<input type="text" name="username" :required="condition ? true : false">
```

Answer (score 3):

In html use

```
<input :required="condition" />
```

And define in data property like

```
data () {
   return {
      condition: false
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use computed too

```
<input :required="isRequired" />
```

Computed:

```
computed: {
   isRequired () {
      return someLogic //Boolean, true or false
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `v-bind`

`v-bind="{ ...(type && { variant: type })`

Answer (score 1):

In vuejs you have something called v-show which conditionally render the element within the DOM, whereas v-if just won't show on the screen but would still exist on DOM.

You can try this code

use template, don't use the v-show condition within the button attributes

```
<template v-show="isRequired">
    <button >Important Button</button>
</template>
```

this "isRequired" seems like its a computed property so make sure you specify the correct logic within  that

Answer (score 0):

I had a form that would require to fill bank detail input filled; if user selected that it had an account.

My solution (using Vue 3 composition) is simple

Create a ref variable initially set to false; that would be used to either have the required attribute or not

```
const isRequired = ref(false)
```

I added on change event on account;

```
<select id="account" v-model="form.account" 
@change="isRequired=!isRequired">
        <option value="YES">YES</option>
        <option value="NO">NO</option>
      </select>

<input type="text" name="bank_details" v-model="form.bank_details" 
:required="isRequired" />
```

so when user select that they have an account; bank-detail input would have the required attribute added to it.

Answer (score 0):

From typescript:

```
type 'string | undefined'
```

If you not need attribute set value to `undefined`