# Check if input has required attribute + VueJs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I have the following code to check if an input field has the required attribute set on it.

```
computed: {        
    isRequired: function (input) {

        input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

        for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
            return this.input.hasAttribute('required') ? 'test-class' : '';  
        }


    }
}
```

And the html template with code for the input component.

```
<div :class="isRequired" class="o-pf-required pull-left">*</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-6" style="padding-right: 0px">

    <!-- 
          padding-right: 0px here cancels out padding on the bootstrap 
          col-lg-12 wrapper keeping the 15px padding of the outer div consistant. 
    -->

        <input :type="type" class="o-pf-input" :class="isCheckBox" :placeholder="placeholder" :name="placeholder" :required="isRequired ? true : false" :value = 'value' @input="value = $event.target.value">
        <label :for="placeholder"> {{ placeholder }} </label>
    </div>
```

What I want to achieve is to apply the test-class to the element where the o-pf-required class is to hide the asterisk but the browser gives me the following error:

[image]

A related issue on this: [VueJS conditionally add an attribute for an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874314/vuejs-conditionally-add-an-attribute-for-an-element)

Comment: `this` in vue computed and methods is always point to current vm instance.Not the input element during iteration.

Comment: Oops. You're right. I forget.

Comment: Hmm, I had an answer that wasn't exactly what you need. Can't you set the required attribute via Vue's data? This will make it a lot easier to check if the input is required. If not, try going with refs (https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) perhaps

Comment: What I did was set required as a props value and bind it like this :required="" to the input element in the template. I also tried to set it in the data object but it kept saying that it is set as a prop and told me to use the prop value instead. I will have a look at refs. Thanks @CaptainCarl

Comment: If you set a :required prop you need something like :required="true/false". You don't have to set a value as a prop, just as a data attribute. (`data () { isRequired: true;}` and `<input :required="isRequired" />`

Comment: It's not working yet though.