# Vuejs append data-attribute conditionally

Tags: vue.js, conditional-statements, custom-data-attribute

I try to add conditionally a data attribute value to my vue list on loop and I try the following

```
<ul data-parent="{{model.parent_id !== null ? model.parent_id : 0}}"></ul>
```

but in this case the list do not renders anymore, if dump out outside html tag `{{model.parent_id !== null ? model.parent_id : 0}}` than I see the correct output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VueJS conditionally add an attribute for an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874314/vuejs-conditionally-add-an-attribute-for-an-element)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `:` before that and I would create a computed property like this.

```
computed: {
     parentId() {
       if (this.model.parent_id !== null)
          return this.model.parent_id
       return 0;
     }

}

<ul :data-parent="parentId"></ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

The right Syntax

```
<ul :data-parent="{{(model.parent_id !== null) ? model.parent_id : 0}}"></ul>
```