# How to conditionally add attributes in vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In vue, I have this

```
<v-dialog v-model="data_table.dialog">
```

and I have a observable variable `is_mobile`. I want it so that the above tag looks like this

```
<v-dialog v-model="data_table.dialog">
```

when `is_mobile` is false. And look like this

```
<v-dialog fullscreen hide-overlay transition="dialog-bottom-transition" v-model="data_table.dialog">
```

when `is_mobile` is true.

How can I do it?

I only know how to set the attribute value, but in this case, I want the attribute itself to be included or not, and for the transition, attribute and value included or attribute not included. Basically exactly the result as shown above, and not like `fullscreen="true"`/`fullscreen="false"`.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VueJS conditionally add an attribute for an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874314/vuejs-conditionally-add-an-attribute-for-an-element)

Comment: could you put both in, and add v-if="is_mobile" for the conditional rendering of the correct element?

Comment: yes, but the contents of the tag is a lot, so I don't want to repeat it twice.

Comment: @ChrisG that still adds the value true or false to the attribute, it doesn't actually remove or keep it.

Comment: As the docs and the comment to the linked question say, if an attribute's value evaluates to something falsey, it's omitted from the rendered HTML.

Comment: how can I either omit it, or keep it with a certain value?

Comment: something like `<v-dialog fullscreen="is-mobile" hide-overlay="is-mobile" ..`

Comment: I mean for transition, either omit it or keep it as `transition="dialog-bottom-transition"`.

Comment: Seems to me like you'd have to add the transition in JS in a method or a computed.

Comment: I think the best solution would be to use v-if with the element
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if

Answer (score 0):

In Vue.js attributes or bindings can be set dynamically by using [v-bind](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-bind) directive.

For example above it can be presented as a computed property:

```
computed: {
  dialogBindings () {
    if (!this.is_mobile) {
      return {
        fullscreen: true,
        hideOverlay: true,
        transition: 'dialog-bottom-transition'
      }
    }
    return {}
  }
}
```

And used inside component's template:

```
<v-dialog   
  v-model="data_table.dialog"
  v-bind="dialogBindings"
>
```