# Add v-html attribute only if slot not given

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

Consider the following in a component snipet:

```
<tr v-for="row in rows" :key="row[rowKey]">
   <td v-for="col in cols">
      <slot v-if="col.bSlot" :name="col.bSlot" :row="row"></slot>
      <template v-else v-html="formatField(row, col)"></template>
   </td>
</tr>
```

Above I want to render a slot if given and if not to render a string returned by a formatting function unescaped. This did not work because I found out that v-html does not work with templates. The following works but you need extra unnecessary div tags that I don't want:

```
<td v-for="col in cols">
   <slot v-if="col.bSlot" :name="col.bSlot" :row="row"></slot>
   <div v-else v-html="formatField(row, col)"></div>
</td>
```

It would be nice if this still worked but has been deprecated:

```
<td v-for="col in cols">
   <slot v-if="col.bSlot" :name="col.bSlot" :row="row"></slot>
   <template v-else>
      {{{formatField(row, col)}}}
   </template>
</td>
```

The only other option I am left with is this but because there is no where to put the v-else I made the formatField() return nothing if a slot is given:

```
<td v-for="col in cols" v-html="formatField(row, col)">
   <slot v-if="col.bSlot" :name="col.bSlot" :row="row"></slot>
</td>

formatField(row, col) {
   if (col.bSlot) return;  // also tried returning null, undefined, and ''
   ...
}
```

However now the slot doesn't render when one is provided. It seems like Vue ignores the slot if v-html is provided. So how do I not provide v-html when the col.bSlot is not provided?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VueJS conditionally add an attribute for an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874314/vuejs-conditionally-add-an-attribute-for-an-element)

Comment: No, I don't see how its in any way related other than matching on key words. Read my post carefully and you'll see its a different question.

Answer (score 0):

You can place default value if slot is not given -
[Fallback-Content](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Fallback-Content)

How about this:

```
1 <td v-for="col in cols">
2  <slot :name="col.bSlot" :row="row">
3     {{ formatField(row, col) }}
4     // <-- this is a comment
5     // <span v-html="formatField(row, col)"></span>
6   </slot>
7 </td>
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as the second code sample I have above that explains this solution with the caveat that there would be an unnecessary element added (<div> in my case and <span> in yours). That's what I did not like about that solution and was looking for one without the unnecessarily added elements.

Comment: @BrobicVripiat use line 3 then `{{ formatField(row, col) }}`. And in your `formatField` method `return` string you need.