# Show Tooltip icon next to textfield label using Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, tooltip, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify's component tooltip. But I am not sure how to implement it right next to the label.

This is how I have it right now.

```html
<v-tooltip right>
  <v-icon slot="activator" dark color="primary">info</v-icon>
  <span>Please enter the user information correctly.</span>
</v-tooltip>
<v-text-field label="Information" v-model="dummy.info"> </v-text-field>
```

[image: Image 1]

I want to tooltip icon right next to the Information Label. Please suggest me how can I achieve that.

Update 1

```
<v-text-field label="Information" v-model="dummy.info">
 <template v-slot:append>
  <v-icon slot="activator" dark color="primary">info</v-icon>
  <span>Please enter the user information correctly.</span>
 </template>
</v-text-field>
```

[image: Image 2]

Update 2

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="dummy.info"
  label='Information'
  append-icon="info"
  suffix="Please enter the user information correctly."
/>
```

[image: Image 3]

Answer (score 1):

You can append things to a `v-text-field` using the `append` slot.

```html
    <v-text-field label="Prepend" prepend-icon="mdi-map-marker" />
```

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#api

```html
<v-text-field>
  <template v-slot:append>
    <v-icon slot="activator" dark color="primary">info</v-icon>
    <span>Please enter the user information correctly.</span>
  </template>
</v-text-field>
```

### For Vuetify 1.xx

```html
<v-text-field
  v-model="dummy.info"
  label="Information"
  append-icon="info"
  suffix="Please enter the user information correctly."
/>
```

https://v1.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#example-prefixes-and-suffixes
https://v1.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/text-fields#example-icon

Comment: Please check update 1, I did as you suggested. But now the icon doesn't appear at all

Comment: I tested it on a Vuetify project and it works. What version of Vuetify do you have ?

Comment: "vuetify": "^1.0.5"

Comment: I see. You need a different syntax for this version. See above

Comment: Please check the update 2. The message is always appearing and the icon is not right after the label

Comment: You can read the documentation of Vue.js to understand how to do conditional binding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874314/vuejs-conditionally-add-an-attribute-for-an-element
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Comment: Can you help me a little more? I couldn't figure out

Comment: This solution works partially - it shows the tooltip, but after the form field, not after the label as the user requested and I am hoping to do as well... any further help?

Answer (score 0):

This snippet should work for you...

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900&ext=.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
        <v-text-field>
          <template v-slot:label>
            What about <strong>icon</strong> here? 
            <v-tooltip bottom>
              <template #activator="{ on, attrs }">
                <v-icon class="mb-2" small v-on="on" v-bind="attrs" style="vertical-align: middle">
                  mdi-information
                </v-icon>
              </template> And here is the information...
          </v-tooltip>
          </template>
        </v-text-field>
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
```