# Vue3 passing required attribute to child if its true for the parent

Tags: vuejs3

I'm creating an input component and I want to pass a required property in, based on a boolean from the parent component

```
#Parent component
<Input 
   :required="false"
/>
```

```
#Child component
<input 
     @input="event => $emit('update:value', event.target.value)"
     :required="required" 
/>
```

The problem is, when the required from the parent component is false, it still puts `required` into the html (which the browser reads as required).

How can I achieve this?

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 1):

For VueJs 2 or earlier version you can use

```
<input :required="test ? true : false">
```

in VueJs 3 you have to use the null to prevent the rendering of the attribute in html tag.

```
 <input :required="test ? true : null">
```

[VueJS conditionally add an attribute for an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874314/vuejs-conditionally-add-an-attribute-for-an-element/64598898#64598898)

Answer (score 0):

You should explain more. I provide a situation as you describe in `stackblitz` where I link it [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-cs99w1?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FHelloWorld.vue). It works and it is a simple form with submit when you change the `required` value in `App.vue` you could see the input element in `HelloWorld.vue` is changing in the inspector. Hope you find it usefull.

Comment: Hi Ghazai. Thank you for the stackblitz. The problem with that is, if required is false, there is no input box.

Comment: Sorry, I was testing something else on it and now removed additional `v-if`. it's working now.

Comment: Did you check it? Does it work?

Comment: Yeah. If you set it to false and inspect the element of the input you'll see it says <input required="">, which is correct, but from a browser validation point of view, it thinks required is set

Comment: It's weird because I'm checking the element in the chrome inspector and it doesn't have any attribute when value is set to false and so it doesn't check the validation of required. what browser are you checking in?