# Vuetify 2->3 Migration: what to do when v-list-item-icon has a v-if conditional

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I have reworked this post to just be about `v-list-item-icon`; if you are arriving here looking for that, there is an answer down below.

It was suggested in a comment that since I was asking a number of migration questions, I split this into multiple posts. I have done so now. These are those posts:

- [Regarding replacing `app`/`clipped-left`/`offset-y`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76232332/vuetify-2-3-replacing-removed-properties-app-clipped-left-offset-y-with-order)
- [Regarding replacing `v-list-item-content`/`v-list-item-group`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76232385/vuetify-2-3-replacing-removed-v-list-item-content-v-list-item-group)
- [Regarding replacing `.v-application` / `rounded` / `flat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76232424/vuetify-2-3-replacing-removed-styles-v-application-rounded-flat)

Someone already helped me with the `v-list-item-icon` issue, though, so I am reworking the rest of this post to just be about that in case someone else finds this.

---

The [migration guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/upgrade-guide/) says a number of properties has been removed, but the docs are incredibly vague on what to do to replace them.

I am *not* a front-end dev, but I've been tasked with updating some very old dependencies, and part of that is migrating from Vuetify 2 to Vuetify 3. I've done my best to follow the migration guide, but I'm having trouble with `v-list-item-icon`.

While it seems clear I need to replace

```
<v-list-item
  class="mr"
  v-for="item in userItems"
  :key="item.title"
  link
  @click="clickUserMenuItem(item.routeName)"
>
  <v-list-item-icon>
    <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
  </v-list-item-icon>
```

with

```
<v-list-item
  class="mr"
  v-for="item in userItems"
  :key="item.title"
  link
  @click="clickUserMenuItem(item.routeName)"
  icon="{{item.icon}}"
>
```

it is not clear what to do if I have

```
<v-list-item-icon v-if="item.icon">
  <v-icon>{{ item.icon }}</v-icon>
</v-list-item-icon>
```

... do I need `icon="{{v-if={{item.icon}}}}"`?

Thank you!

Comment: Whew, so many questions, I don't know where to start, and it would be a mess. Maybe make this one about the `order` prop, and then create another question about updating `v-list` and another one about the variants (rounded, flat)?

Comment: sure, that seems reasonable, although there is already an answer for the icon bit. What's the best protocol for something like splitting a question into constituent parts? Should I leave a comment at the top of this question with links to the other threads?

Comment: @MoritzRingler thank you for the suggestion. I have split this into 4 different questions as suggested. (Links at the top; this post is now only about the icon question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<v-list-item
  class="mr"
  v-for="item in userItems"
  :key="item.title"
  link
  @click="clickUserMenuItem(item.routeName)"
  :icon="item.icon || null"
/>
```

you really do not need it with 'item.icon || null' < 'item.icon' would be enough..

see this answer:
[VueJS conditionally add an attribute for an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874314/vuejs-conditionally-add-an-attribute-for-an-element/64598898#64598898)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: regardless of what the bot said, that seems clear enough to me. That resolves one of the linting issues - thanks!