# Vuetify 2->3 replacing removed v-list-item-content / v-list-item-group

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm trying to upgrade from Vuetify/Vue 2->3. I'm not a front-end developer, just tasked with upgrading some legacy code to keep things functioning. Unfortunately, the [migration guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/upgrade-guide/) seems to assume a level of baseline CSS knowledge and doesn't provide examples of how to fix everything that was removed.

One of the things I'm struggling with is replacing the deprecated `v-list-item-content` / `v-list-item-group` in this block of code:

```
    <v-navigation-drawer :rail="mini" permanent clipped app width="200">
      <v-list density="compact">
        <v-list-item-group v-model="selected">
          <v-list-item
            v-for="item in items"
            :key="item.title"
            link
            :disabled="item.disabled"
            :icon="item.icon || null"
          >
            <v-list-item-content>
              <v-list-item-title>{{ item.title }}</v-list-item-title>
            </v-list-item-content>
          </v-list-item>
        </v-list-item-group>
      </v-list>
    </v-navigation-drawer>
```

The migration guide just says:

> v-list-item-content has been removed, lists use CSS grid for layout now instead.

and

> v-list-item-group has been removed, just add value to list items to make them selectable and bind v-model:selected on v-list to get the selected value.

I have no idea what they mean by "use CSS grid for layout" and since I don't know CSS, I'm stuck. And the note about v-list-item-group talks about *multiple* things with no examples!

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

(I originally asked this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76224267/vuetify-2-3-migration-guide-has-unclear-steps-for-various-removed-properties) and it was suggested that I split that into multiple questions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The migration guide could be improved! Hopefully this helps...

> v-list-item-content has been removed, lists use CSS grid for layout
> now instead.

If you look at the output under version 3 you will see this element is there `.v-list-item__content` with associated grid styles so you no longer need to add this to achieve the same thing.

> v-list-item-group has been removed, just add value to list items to
> make them selectable and bind v-model:selected on v-list to get the
> selected value.

`Add value to list items to make them selectable`.

```
<v-list :items="items"></v-list>
```

`Bind v-model:selected on v-list to get the selected value`.

This doesnt work, however there are events emitted so if you need the value, you can get it with the following:

```
<v-list
  :items="items" 
  @update:selected="selected" // <<< Listen for event
/>
```

**Example:** [Codepen](https://codepen.io/alexpetergill/pen/RweJorK/d54258e6084669cd6af0b986eebf471b)

Comment: so you're saying regarding the v-list-item-content I can just delete that section?

Comment: @user3534080 yes exactly that