# Vuetify 2->3 replacing removed styles .v-application / rounded / flat

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

I'm trying to upgrade from Vuetify/Vue 2->3. I'm not a front-end developer, just tasked with upgrading some legacy code to keep things functioning. Unfortunately, the [migration guide](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/upgrade-guide/) seems to assume a level of baseline CSS knowledge and doesn't provide examples of how to fix everything that was removed.

I'm struggling to figure out how to migrate `rounded` and `flat` in the following code snippet:

```
      <v-select
        class="mr-2 filter-custom-input"
        slot="prepend-inner"
        v-model="field"
        :items="fields"
        menu-props="auto"
        label="Field"
        hide-details
        single-line
        density="compact"
        rounded
        flat
        theme="dark"
      />
```

and `.v-application` in this one (if it even needs to be done?):

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
.v-application--is-ltr .v-list-item__icon:first-child,
.v-application--is-ltr .mr {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Unfortunately, the only advice the migration guide on these is:

- `rounded` prop has been removed. Apply a rounded css class to the menu content element instead. e.g. `.rounded-te`
- Global styles previously included as `.v-application p` or `.v-application ul` are no longer included. If you need margin for `p`, or padding-left for `ul` and `ol`, set it manually in your root component’s `<style>` tag

The above `rounded` guidance doesn't work just by replacing `rounded` with `.rounded-te` (not to mention it talks about this in a different type of control).

It says flat was removed from some other controls and replaced by "a single variant prop", but attempting to replace `flat` with `variant="flat"` gave me a syntax error.

Thank you!

(I originally asked this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76224267/vuetify-2-3-migration-guide-has-unclear-steps-for-various-removed-properties) and it was suggested that I split that into multiple questions)

Answer (score 1):

You can still use [`rounded`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-field/#props-rounded) and [`flat`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-field/#props-flat), they just moved to the underlying VField component.

I think your v2 select would end up without any frame at all, in which case `rounded` won't do anything visible. Add `variant="solo"` with `flat` to get the same effect in v3 (see [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNqlUctugzAQ/BXLl1wAK0kPFUqr9DviHBxYVLd+yTZUVcS/d22IgsglUm/szHhndjhd6Ydz1dADrekhgnZKRHjnhpDDUArn8mcetJCGNEqE8MapE+UrpzOZ6QAKmkhuCCG1xHVJe9oWu2J/5pQocQGFyKTl9C4ehJfCxMRZZZeMt71pob0DHSacJ3ZLx6Z4U24cpuAHtjgIx9B46SIJEPtES+2sj+RKPHRkJJ23mmywiU0Ws0mNOlrQSYoervoK1mBX12TFZyJwWpOMJAxXpJnTzxhdqBlrWoPPWlBy8JWByIzT7Igy5nsTpYaytfq4r/bVlrUyxCVcQdDlxdufAB6XcFosbKLsfp+wmpXosKteJocZKvGPhGTxsJqh3wC+9IDte/DPXrR6trxqRT1cltxHbkbsW0nzHVZVNyHXfLqF/NfJeVnadE6GY0FzTnTOD+j5D6IuA1k=))

---

As to the `v-application--is-ltr` class, it is called `v-locale--is-ltr` in V3.

If you still need it depends on your app, those are custom rules. Check if the custom `mr` class is used and how the margin on the first icon in lists look like (I think list icons are now set through the prepend slot, so the class would be `.v-list-item__prepend .v-icon`)